# how can I reliably check that requests to my service file have come from my website?

Tags: php, ajax, security, http-referer

I have a service.php class that I use to service AJAX calls from my website. To prevent other people accessing the service using PHP CURL I would normally check the request has come from mysite, and if they are not then just redirect to my home page e.g.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://www.mysite.com"){
   header('location: http://www.mysite.com');
   exit;
}
```

I read in the PHP holy bible:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

that

> "Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted."

So if this method is not reliable, my question is how can I reliably check that requests to my service file have come from my website?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: the answer is simple: you **can't**. Even if you stop a fellow thief for a while, he will come here to stackoverflow and get full and exact solution how to avoid it.

Comment: As long as 'woot586' doesn't post his secretstring here he'll be fine I think?

Comment: Also, it is very important for you noob developers to understand that requests are coming **not from your website** but from **client's computer**

Comment: @Nanne what will stop them from emulating ajax calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a small session cookie, which includes time of page request, IP of the requester and some secret string which changes from time to time (i.e. is valid for an hour or so). The cookie must be encrypted. Now when the AJAX call is made, you check the cookie, compare the IP, check the secret string and act accordingly.

But to say the truth, this will make hacker's task more complicated, but not impossible. So you'd need to add HTTPS to the equation, and even then a good troyan on client's computer would make false request possible. But for most scenarios the above + HTTPS would drive the attacker away.

Comment: HTTPS itself is not a silver bullet. Client certificates you probably mean. Though I doubt the OP will go so far.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel  if you re-read my answer, you will see, that HTTPS is used as a helper to prevent man-in-the-middle leakage of the cookie, which can be misused to create a false request on the different system (by forging IP of the originator). HTTPS limits possibilities of the hacker to breaking into user's computer.

Comment: if you reread the opening post, it's just a silly ajax service. "man in the middle attack", my foot.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think there will always be security issues its just a case of reducing the possibility of it occuring. The method above has more checks in increasing the possibility of catching a hack attempt. I am now using an encrypted cookie which contains a hash to compare against my secret string. Also in this cookie I have stored the ip address to refer to and i'm checking http referer (if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily I think. What you could do is make your own files always post some sort of passphrase. Say you sent some data (datetime?), and a hash of `"datetime+secretstring"`

As only you know the secretstring, only you can create the hash. Recreate the hash in your 2nd file using the received datetime, and check if the sent hash is correct.

Requests from other sites will not have your hash and datetime, or at least not the correct one.